# Check which class has called function

Tags: java

How can I check which class has called my method?

For example: If Class A uses the MethodB in the Class C than, the function should do something else than the function would do, if Class B calls the MethodB.

I can't add a boolean or something like that to the method.

Comment: Do not implement logic like this. If a method depends on who calls the method, then it is not very reusable. If you need to do some specific things different, look into command pattern or something like that.

Comment: Good beginners question, however don't do this.  Create separate methods.  If you post a code sample then we could give you better advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no good way of doing this - and it's fundamentally a bad design, IMO. If ClassA and ClassB want different things to happen, they should call different methods.

The *only* time this is reasonable in my experience is when trying to work out a simple way of initializing loggers, where basically you want the calling class name to be part of the logger name. One horrible way of doing that is to throw and catch an exception, then look at its stack trace. But avoid if possible...

Comment: But what if you _do_ want to know the caller, not for manipulating a logic, but maybe, say, logging stuff for some important reason?

Comment: @Aniket: If you're logging a stack trace (which you normally would), that would include the caller anyway. But my main point is that the OP wrote that the function would do different things based on the caller, which sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: It's only a "short-Time" solution for me, because there are JUnit-Tests which have to work, and only work with the old parts, so I have to check, if the method which called my method was from the JUnit-Class. Than it has to do some old stuff.

Answer (score 5):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

javadoc:

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack,
>   which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

and the documentation of what you can get from each `StackTraceElement`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

```
getClassName()
getFileName()
getLineNumber() 
getMethodName()
```

Comment: Technically, yes, but please don't give out advise this this without a warning against using it.  A little knowledge etc...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to find the name of the class for a calling method. Here is how you can achieve it.

```
class A {

    public void testMethodCall() {
        new C().testMethod();
    }
}

class B {
  public void testMethodCall() {
      new C().testMethod();
  }
}

class C {

    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("Called from class : " +Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName());
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.testMethodCall();
        b.testMethodCall();
    }

}
```

Output

> Called from class : A
>
> Called from class : B

You can use this sample code to adapt to your need.

Comment: For some reason in my case it returns every time "Called from class C" (where it is defined ...) Here is my code:             Log.i(TAG, message.toString() +
                    " Called from class: " +
                    Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[2].className)

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
     B().foo()
}

class B {
     fun foo() {
         val className = Throwable().stackTrace[1].className.substringAfterLast('.')
         Log.d(TAG, className) //prints "A"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print stack trance for that manner:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    new Exception("").printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering too late. You can use **Thread.dumpStack()** to check who is calling your function.

suppose you want to check who is calling function ABC(). Then you can write the code as follows:

```
function ABC(){
   Thread.dumpStack()
   ......
   .....
   Rest of your code

}
```

When Thread.dumpStack() will get execute, then it will print a stacktrace.
You can refer [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_dumpstack.htm)
Note that, this function is not only limited to threads, it can be used anywhere/